# jQuery: dealing with a space in the id attribute

Tags: jquery

I have an  element with id="A B". The following code **fails**:

```
<input type="text" id="A B">
<script>$("#A B").click(function(){alert();});</script>
```

The following code **does not fail**:

```
<input type="text" id="AB">
<script>$("#AB").click(function(){alert();});</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery IDs with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While it’s technically invalid to have a space in an ID attribute value in HTML (see @karim79’s answer), you can actually select it using jQuery.

See http://mothereffingcssescapes.com/#A%20B:

```
<script>
  // document.getElementById or similar
  document.getElementById('A B');
  // document.querySelector or similar
  $('#A\\ B');
</script>
```

jQuery uses a Selectors API-like syntax, so you could use `$('#A\\ B');` to select the element with `id="A B"`.

To target the element in CSS, you could escape it like this:

```
<style>
  #A\ B {
    background: hotpink;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this also works with Capybara when trying to select an id with a space.

Answer (score 16):

As they mentioned you shouldn't use spaces in id.
But anyway, wouldn't this be working for you?

```
$("[id='A B']").click(...)
```

**EDIT**: yes it works, tested it!!! Don't kill me, standard-lovers!! ;-P

Answer (score 13):

Neither HTML4 nor HTML5 allows space characters in ID attribute values.

> The HTML 4.01 spec states that ID tokens must begin with a letter
>   ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).
>   For the class attribute, there is no such limitation. Classnames can
>   contain any character, and they don’t have to start with a letter to
>   be valid.
>
> HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on the id attribute. The
>   only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are
>   that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty),
>   and that it can’t contain any space characters.

Source:

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: +1 This is correct. However, while it’s technically invalid to have a space in an ID attribute value in HTML, [you can make it work if you escape your jQuery selector correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802765/jquery-dealing-with-a-space-in-the-id-attribute/7873035#7873035).

Answer (score 5):

There should not be space in an id, but this seems to works :

```
$("[id=A B]")
```

Comment: it seems we posted it at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

That quote is pulled from another stackoverflow answer: [jquery IDs with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces)