# Need to register javascript function in code behind then call it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function that scrolls to an anchor:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
    var aTag = $("a[name='" + aid + "']");
    if (aTag.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 100
        }, 'slow');
        aTag.closest('.subpanel').effect("highlight", 5000);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<a id="A2" class="gridLabel" name="Add Action Item">
    <span id="MainContent_Label19" title="Add / Edit an action item.">Add / Edit Action Item</span>
</a>
```

I have to call a server side event that performs some sort of action.  Once the action is completed I need to call this `scrollToAnchor`.  I tried this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "OpenActions", "$(function(){ 
 function scrollToAnchor(aid) { var aTag = $('a[name=''' + aid + ''']');if (aTag.length) 
{$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 100 }, 
'slow');aTag.closest('.subpanel').effect('highlight', 5000);}} $('#tblAction').show(); 
scrollToAnchor('Add Action Item');});", true);
```

However I get errors in the `console` probably because of my `' '` and `" "`.  Can someone help form this for me.

I also tried:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "OpenActions", "$(function()
{function scrollToAnchor(aid) { var aTag = $('a[name=\"' + aid + '\"]' + ']');if 
(aTag.length) {$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 100 }, 
'slow');aTag.closest('.subpanel').effect('highlight', 5000);}} $('#tblAction').show(); 
scrollToAnchor('Add Action Item');});", true);
```

Comment: Care to share the errors from your `console`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be here:

```
'a[name=''' + aid + ''']'
```

Try replacing that with:

```
'a[name=' + aid + ']'
```

Or if you need quotes in the value of name:

```
'a[name=\'' + aid + '\']'
// Or
'a[name=\"' + aid + '\"]'
```

Comment: This is almost working but here's the error i get: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[name=Add Action Item]]

Comment: @JonH: Then you'll need to use one of the last 2 examples.

Comment: Now Im getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string  with the first example of the third example you posted.  Here is my code: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "OpenActions", "$(function(){function scrollToAnchor(aid) { var aTag = $('a[name=\'' + aid + '\']' + ']');if (aTag.length) {$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 100 }, 'slow');aTag.closest('.subpanel').effect('highlight', 5000);}} $('#tblAction').show(); scrollToAnchor('Add Action Item');});", true);`

Comment: And if I use the last example I get this `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[name="Add Action Item"]] `

Comment: @JonH You have 2 closing brackets now: [...Item"]] <- from: $('a[name=\'' + aid + '\']' + ']')

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is put the function on the page (or in a js file loaded by the page) and then simply register a script like so:

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), 
"OpenActions", "scrollToAnchor('Add Action Item');", true);
```

From what I can tell, you don't need to register the entire script on each server side event.  You just need to run the function with a given argument.

Comment: I tried that but the scrolling doesnt appear to work, no errors though.

Comment: What does the <a> tag look like (the one you're trying to scroll to), if you "View Source" from the browser?  If your function doesn't find the tag, I don't think it would throw an error.

Comment: mikey looks like this `<a id="A2" class="gridLabel" name="Add Action Item">
                                                <span id="MainContent_Label19" title="Add / Edit an action item.">Add / Edit Action Item</span>
                                                </a>`

Comment: what happens if you do this:  ... if (aTag.length) { alert('found it'); $('html,body').animate({ ...  does the alert fire?  Apologies to those who know of a better way to debug javascript than inserting alert tags, please let me know and I'll start doing that ASAP! ;)

Comment: I think the spaces in the name are what's killing you, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802765/jquery-dealing-with-a-space-in-the-id-attribute

Answer (score -1):

Prefix your string with @, like so

```cs
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "OpenActions", @"$(function(){ 
 function scrollToAnchor(aid) { var aTag = $('a[name=' + aid + ']');if (aTag.length) 
{$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 100 }, 
'slow');aTag.closest('.subpanel').effect('highlight', 5000);}} $('#tblAction').show(); 
scrollToAnchor('Add Action Item');});", true);
```