# jQuery spaces in id name

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

**HTML**

```
<span id="plus one">Plus One</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#plus one").hide();
```

The jQuery to hide the span doesn't work and I suspect it is because there is a space in the `id` name.

I cannot change the `id` name or use a `class` or`name` as an alternative.  Is there anyone other way to deal with this?  All feedback welcomed - thanks.

Comment: Try `$('#plus#one')` though I'm not sure if that'll work.

Comment: html ids do not allow multiple values / spaces.  however, classes allow multiple values.  try <span id="plus-one" class="plus one"> then something like $('#plus-one.plus.one') will work and should illustrate an answer to your question

Comment: start by using valid `ID`...space is not valid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate - didn't find the 'dealing with a space' in my searches - happy for this to be closed.

Comment: @charlietfl - I couldn't agree more - however I'm dealing with inherited code that would require major work to overcome that issue.  I appreciate this is a `dirty-fix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use attribute selector:

```
$("span[id='plus one']").hide();
```

or

```
$("#plus\\ one").hide(); // copied from below ref.
```

Ref: [jQuery: dealing with a space in the id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802765/jquery-dealing-with-a-space-in-the-id-attribute)

Comment: Thanks, appreciated, couldn't seem to find the question on stackoverflow though.