# How to handle spaces in div id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting id of div from external source and in that spaces also coming in id , how to get the value of id. Here is my div example:

```
<div id="123456ABC" class="classname" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'33',bb.value,'1000')"></div>
<div id="78904 bbc" class="classname1" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'55',bb.value,'2000')"></div>
```

I need to get the class name from the id. Here is what I am doing:

```
function AddValue(aa, bb) {
    var classOfDiv = $('#123456ABC').attr('class');
    var classOfDivs = $('#8904 bbc').attr('class');
    alert(classOfDiv);
    alert(classOfDivs);
}
```

The first alert is working fine but second is not fetching a value. How can I handle this? All the values are dynamic.

Comment: The question is moot as `id` attributes cannot have spaces in. The HTML you're retrieving is invalid for that reason

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan id is coming as space as response from external application

Comment: $("[id='content Module']").whatever();

Comment: @vellaidurai change this thing `div id="78904 bbc"` do something like `div id="78904bbc"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery IDs with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces)

Comment: @vellaidurai in which case you should inform them that they need to fix this issue. You could use an attribute selector as a workaround though

Comment: A duplicate of a duplicate. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802765/jquery-dealing-with-a-space-in-the-id-attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("div[id='78904 bbc']")` to access element which has spaces in id, Try:

```js
var classOfDiv = $("div[id='123456ABC']").attr('class');        
var classOfDivs = $("div[id='78904 bbc']").attr('class');
alert(classOfDiv);
alert(classOfDivs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="123456ABC" class="classname" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'33',bb.value,'1000')"></div>
<div id="78904 bbc" class="classname1" onclick="javascript:AddValue(aa.value,'55',bb.value,'2000')"></div>
```

Comment: so strange...why downvoting??