# How to find a dynamic element and send text through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

EDIT: Not sure if it really helps to figure it out, but this is Sharepoint based.

I have an element with special character which the Webdriver can't locate.

```
var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("Tasrit_6aecdca9-e3b9-4141-ae36-d537784f9592_$TextField_inplacerte")));
element.SendKeys("foo");
```

I guess it is the `$` that causes the problem.

On the contrary , I found it by using :

```
var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div[id*='Tasrit_6aecdca9-e3b9-4141-ae36-d537784f9592']")));
element[2].FindElement(By.TagName("p")).SendKeys("foo");
```

The test passes that way(seemingly), but the value isn't really being sent to the field.
Unfortunately, there is no `input` tag on the element's hierarchy, and when inserting the text manually , I can then see that the value was inserted to the `<p>` tag. But , as shown, when using the `<p>` tag , it doesn't really help.

The HTML:

```html
<div class="ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field" id="Tasrit_6aecdca9-e3b9-4141-ae36-d537784f9592_$TextField_inplacerte" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="Tasrit_6aecdca9-e3b9-4141-ae36-d537784f9592_$TextField_inplacerte_label" style="min-height: 84px;" contenteditable="true" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-multiline="true" RteDirty="true">
  <p>
    <span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" RteNodeId="1"></span>
    <span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span>
  ​</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML

Comment: Check the extra space, see below.

Comment: This ID seems dynamic. And you have 3 IDs like that?

Comment: yes. I should send thanks to Microsoft Dynamics CRM :) ..but in this case it just looks dynamic , it isn't. it stays the same each and every time I'm running. anyway, it happens when I'm using id* (contains) as well

Comment: What happens if you send the text to the parent `<div>`?

Comment: same. Test pass, but nothing really happens.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing two `FindElement*` you can do it in single step as follows:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.ms-rtestate-write.ms-rteflags-0.ms-rtestate-field[id^='Tasrit_'][aria-labelledby$='_inplacerte_label']>p"))).SendKeys("foo");
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field' and starts-with(@id,'Tasrit_')][contains(@aria-labelledby,'_inplacerte_label')]/p"))).SendKeys("foo");
  ```

---

### Update

However the element looks dynamic to me so you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.ms-rtestate-write.ms-rteflags-0.ms-rtestate-field[id^='Tasrit_'][aria-labelledby$='_inplacerte_label']>p"))).SendKeys("foo");
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0 ms-rtestate-field' and starts-with(@id,'Tasrit_')][contains(@aria-labelledby,'_inplacerte_label')]/p"))).SendKeys("foo");
  ```

Comment: nice one, but the result is still the same. The test passes, but value wasn't really sent to the field.

Comment: @YanivEliav Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: on it . let you know soon

Comment: for some reason, the text("foo") was sent to a different field and not the one I'm pointing to.. maybe because they have the same class(?)

Comment: There are 3 elements have the same class and contains the same part of id you mentioned:  `TextField_inplacerte`

Comment: @YanivEliav Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: thanks for the efforts, unfortuately the result is still the same..very strange behavior

Comment: @YanivEliav Your comments are not helping me either. Sorry, the answer didn't help you to solve your problem but how am I going to improve my post with that feedback? Where are you seeing the error now? Does the line of code identifies the element at all? Or the identification is fine but `SendKeys()` is non-functional? Please update the main question with your detailed observation.

Comment: the identification is ok. it was ok from the very first begining. I would update my original post but nothing really changed. So, the identification is good, but the `SendKeys()` isn't really sedning any data. and if it does, for some reason it sends data for a whole different object which has a different identifiers.

Comment: For some reason I wasn’t able to see this post until you marked another post of mine (with link to this one) as duplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And I guess there is **extra space in that element's id** :) Try this:

```
wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("Tasrit_6aecdca9-e3b9-4141-ae36-d537784f9592_$TextField_inplacerte")));
element.Click();
```

Either that **or the Id value of that element in the DOM is different**, `$TextField_inplacerte` being a variable that parses to eg. spaceMonkey, undefined, 5 etc. Open up the dev tools, find the element, right-click, inspect and confirm the actual Id of the element in the DOM.

You can use dev tools API to search for text in DOM of the currently opened page (with that element in it) if it matches the Id matches if not there is a difference in it. It could be any part eg. 6th character in Id being different :)

Just to make sure that space between 1st part of id and 24 you mention is the problem you can either:

1. look at webdriver's code and see internally what is used to access DOM elements
2. load jquery before testing this out:

   var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElements($('#id containing 
   spaces')).SendKeys("foo");

Basically, instead of using webdriver way to find element, you use jQuery to obtain the element reference. If that works it's the space problem due to bad design of the application having space in element's id

Possibly that is why CSS selector route worked.

Comment: when using dev tools API the id now is `#Tasrit_6aecdca9-e3b9-4141-ae36-d537784f9592_\24 TextField_inplacerte`

Comment: So put in exactly that instead of what you putting in. wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("Tasrit_6aecdca9-e3b9-4141-ae36-d537784f9592_\24 TextField_inplacerte"))); if it is always the same.

Comment: did you notice there is a space between the `24` and `TextField`? I should use it exactly the same?

Comment: nice notice. Here is info about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802765/jquery-dealing-with-a-space-in-the-id-attribute

So it depends on how the element is selected internally in webdriver library. Bottom line here is technically space is not allowed in DOM element's id and should be avoided. I would consider this a bad design of the app / library / whoever gives that id to that element

Answer (score 0):

If `SendKeys()` doesn't work you can try using `JavaScript`

```
IWebElement webElement = element[2].FindElement(By.TagName("p"));
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'arguments[1]')", webElement, "foo");
```

Comment: I have tried it as well..same result...this is a though one, no doubts