# Does getElementByID() method work if ID contains spaces

Tags: javascript, dom, customization

Element i have has spaces within the id attribute which is causing the getElementByID() to not work and not be able to capture the element.

If there any workaround i can do in this. Do i have to remove all white spaces in all element ID values i have.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
var str=document.getElementById('Monica Finolta Sol ID treReport').id;
alert(str);
})
```

Comment: If you have control over your document, you absolutely must get rid of the spaces. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: See also this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802804/7867822

Comment: But when i inspect element and tried in console document.getElementById('Monica Finolta Sol ID treReport').id; i got below response:
"Monica Finolta Sol ID treReport"

Answer (score 1):

Yes! But it is bad practice to have your id contain spaces, as it won't be accessible for a querySelector. Still, it works!

```js
if(document.getElementById('a b')) { 
  console.log("It works!")
}
```

```html
<p id="a b">Text</p>
```

Comment: But in my case i am unable to capture the element & is always returning NULL.

Comment: This is the element <a href="something" id="Monica Finolta Sol ID treReport" target="_blank">Monica Finolta Sol ID treReport</a>

Comment: According to the comment above, you made it work. You are console-logging the id of the element, which as you stated is "Monica Finolta Sol ID treReport". Try to remove `.id`, to console log the entire element.

Comment: Does working in console log guarantee it will work in actual page?

Comment: Generally, yes. The same engine runs the console as the runtime javascript. Note: If my answer helped solve your problem, feel free to accept it (might not be possible as the question has been marked as duplicate).