# Why is my jquery input mask not working?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, mask

I am trying to use the jQuery input mask plug-in (jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js), and I have searched for several examples/solutions, and my code is exactly as other working examples, but it simply won't work for me.  Keep in mind my code is only testing this plug-in for now (trying to get it to work, which will explain why I am trying to apply a date input mask to a name field) My code lies below:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Persons of Interest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Default_Styler.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/person.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/FormHandler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="WrapperDiv">
        <div id="TitleBar">    <!--Beginning of Title Bar-->
            <div style="padding-top: 30px; text-align: center;">Persons of Interest</div>
        </div>                 <!--End of Title Bar-->
        <div id="FormHolder">
            <form action="">
                <p><label>POI Name: </label><input type="text" id="POI Name" name="POI Name" value=""/></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#POI Name").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

Other than that, I can assure you that the referenced jQuery libraries are indeed in
the appropriate directory. (/Scripts/...)

I don't get an error when I click in the input field or anything, it just simply does nothing.

Comment: Not an answer since I really agree you should drop the space from your `id`, but for curiosity's sake this should work (escape the space): `$("#POI\\ Name")` http://jsfiddle.net/xA8GY/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery selectors follow the standard CSS syntax, so the space in the middle of your ID is actually being treated as a descendant selector. Make your life easier: when dealing with jQuery, keep your IDs and classes limited to alphanumerics, hyphen and that's about it.

To clarify: there is a quote/escape syntax in jQuery, but IMHO it's too annoying to deal with, hence I'm not even giving an example of it.

Comment: OMG, I gotta quit adding spaces to my code... Thanks alot! Your answer was exactly why it wasn't working.  It is honestly pascal and camel case from now on...

Answer (score 4):

remove the space from the ID and then try this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#POIName").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are not valid in ID attributes. You should change your id to `$("#POIName")` and update your html as well.

[Jquery-ids-with-spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces) is a similar question that you may find intersting.