# Format date as user types to dd/mm/yyyy in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a solution to provide a user with a friendly field that formats the date accordingly to what they type. I noticed a lot of applications have it set up like that. So for example when a user types the first two numbers it will then insert a /. I am open to any suggestions. Thank you. This is just a standard input type:

```
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required 
pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" 
title="Enter a date in this format MM/DD/YYYY"/>
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: SO is a place where we help you with your code. Show us some effort, and tell us what's going wrong, and we can help.

Comment: It's impossible, the user could be typing anything that doesn't necessarily correspond to a date

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Not quite: `input[type=date]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my jquery input mask not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324800/why-is-my-jquery-input-mask-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work great for me: [How to auto format textbox inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709559/how-to-auto-format-textbox-inputs)

```
    $("input[name='birthdate']:first").keyup(function(e){
    var key=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if(!(key>=0&&key<=9))$(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,$(this).val().length-1));
    var value=$(this).val();
    if(value.length==2||value.length==5)$(this).val($(this).val()+'/');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#birthdate").datepicker();
});

$("input[name='birthdate']:first").keyup(function(e) {
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if (!(key >= 0 && key <= 9)) $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).val().length - 1));
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.length == 2 || value.length == 5) $(this).val($(this).val() + '/');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><label>Birthdate</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" maxlength="10" />
  </td>
</tr>
```