# Select element with percent sign (%) in its id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element like this:

```
<a id="my%20id" href="#">hello</a>
```

I've been trying desperately to select it with jQuery, but cannot. I've tried:

```
$('a#my id')                          // obviously won't work
$('a#my\ id')                         // no such luck
$('a#my%20id')                        // unrecognized expression
$('a#my\%20id')                       // still unrecognized
$('a#' + encodeURIComponent('my id')) // same thing as 'a#my%20id'
```

Is it possible to select this at all with jQuery?

Comment: You don't need the a if you are using an ID selector... Will '#my%20id' work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery IDs with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces)

Comment: @mc10 This is not a duplicate, because the id has been encoded. Before it was encoded, $('a#my\ id') worked fine.

Comment: `$(document.getElementById("my%20id"))` will also work.

Comment: @flaviotsf It's my preference - more self-documenting especially since I am writing a test suite in this case.

Comment: @2rs2ts All of the same solutions work, because the issue is the same: you are using an invalid character in your ID. So your question is still a duplicate.

Comment: @mc10 With all due respect, I'm not exactly asking about what a valid id for an element is. I do note this fact, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use attribute selector, giving id in quotes will get the exact id.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QsM6Y/)**

```
$('[id="my%20id"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the trustworthy `document.getElementById`:

```
$(document.getElementById("my%20id")).text();
```

Performance *should* be better than using an attribute selector, as you rely on a native method call to find the `id`. It's a bit more verbose than the other solutions, if that's an issue.

Comment: I would accept this answer if two things were true: (1) I wasn't working inside of an iframe (d'oh! but that's too XY) and (2) I didn't ask for this specifically in jQuery. But yes, that's a great way to do it normally.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you need a lot of escaping here:

```
$("#my\\%20id").text("HI");
```

`\%` is not a valid escape, you want `\\%` which will escape correctly and get the correct id.

You can check [an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc747/).

Comment: This didn't work, but it may have something to do with my environment and not with the general correctness of your answer. So, upvoted nonetheless.