# Select element by id with trailing spaces

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I can't figure out why I can't get an html element like this:

```
<input name="ctl00$body$frmViewODL$ListViewParametri$ctrl0$txtParametroValoreNum" type="text" value="1" id="body_frmViewODL_ListViewParametri_txtParametroValoreNum_10  " class="boxNum" style="width: 60px">
```

with this jQuery:

```
$('#body_frmViewODL_ListViewParametri_txtParametroValoreMax_10  ')
```

I have tried removing/adding the spaces at the end :-)

PS: If i try

```
document.getElementById('body_frmViewODL_ListViewParametri_txtParametroValoreMax_10  ')
```

it is ok.

**EDIT**

The complete code is a little more complicated...

I have a ListView and I use the ClientIDRowSuffix to let asp.net append the Record key to the id of the control. I want to update an array of values(record) in a single post.

So In html I have an array of TextBox, like this:

```
<input name="ctl00$body$frmViewODL$ListViewParametri$ctrl0$txtParametroValoreNum" type="text" value="1" id="body_frmViewODL_ListViewParametri_txtParametroValoreNum_10  " class="boxNum" style="width: 60px">
<input name="ctl00$body$frmViewODL$ListViewParametri$ctrl1$txtParametroValoreNum" type="text" value="2" id="body_frmViewODL_ListViewParametri_txtParametroValoreNum_11  " class="boxNum" style="width: 60px">
<input name="ctl00$body$frmViewODL$ListViewParametri$ctrl7$txtParametroValoreNum" type="text" value="8" id="body_frmViewODL_ListViewParametri_txtParametroValoreNum_23  " class="boxNum" style="width: 60px">
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get an html element"? You get a 0-length list?

Comment: Why do you create id with space? Please show us your .aspx markup

Comment: I can't post "possible duplicate" anymore as my vote is binding, but see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces  The issue is the spaces in your `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the problem might be jQuery parsing the selector with trailing space. Since usually spaces separate different parts of a selector, jQuery might not treat this trailing space as something that relates to `#` part. To make sure it understands that space is a part of an ID, you might want use attribute selector instead:

```
$("[id='body_frmViewODL_ListViewParametri_txtParametroValoreNum_10  ']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way is let the aspx page parser write what ever it comes and apply attribute selector.(Thanks to @James Montagne comment on a question)

```
$("[id='<%= txtParametroValoreNum.ClientID %>']")
```

Comment: This will exhibit the same problem as the issue is caused by spaces in the `id` value.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, I dont think we intentionally create an id with space at the end. Probably its a developer mistake. Lets wait for his aspx markup :)

Comment: @Murali, apparently OP is well aware of this space, so it seems to be intentional

Comment: @Andrei, Updated by mixing aspx and id selector :)

Comment: @Murali, are you sure `<% %>` will work? Shouldn't it be '<%= %>'?