# Locating element with ID having space in it jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to locate an element in my web page, but it always throws an error at this line:

```
var test = $('table[id$=' + array[i].Id + ']');
```

The error is Object doesn't support this property or method.

array[i].Id is "12312 Tab1"

When I remove the space in the Id, there is no error thrown. My jQuery knowledge is very basic, so I am not quite sure why this error would occur?

Any ideas please?

Comment: ====> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces might help `:)` fiddle it and make a demo.

Comment: try using backslash "12312\ Tab1"

Comment: I always recommend to [read the **documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) first (emphasis mine): *"`jQuery( "[attribute$='value']" )` [...] value: An attribute value. Can be either an **unquoted single word** or a **quoted string**."*

Comment: generally classes can be multiple separated by space but for id there is only one so spacing in id wouldn't be recommended to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var test = $('table[id$="' + array[i].Id + '"]');
```

you need add quotes if the attr value contains space

Comment: wow that was such a quick response! I am checking it out now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either escape the character occurence or wrap whole value in quotes when using in attribute value selector:

```
var test = $('table[id$="' + array[i].Id + '"]');
```

or

```
var test = $('table[id$=' + array[i].Id.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")+ ']');
```