# jquery reference ID with space in name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using jquery with a jquery multi select extension.

For my html syntax:

```
<select multiple="multiple"  id="test">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
</select>
```

I then get the values of the multi-select with:

```
  $(function() {

        $('#test').change(function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
        }).multipleSelect({
            width: '100%'
        });
    });
```

This works 100%.

my question is how do I get this to work when the ID has a space in it. I know it isnt ideal to have a space in an ID or Name but it is what it is currently and I need to get the multiple select options from the ID with a space.
so example:

```
<select multiple="multiple"  id="test two">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    </select>

$(function() {

            $('#test two').change(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
            }).multipleSelect({
                width: '100%'
            });
        });
```

this fails with the space in it.

I have tried a few options like below without any success.

any advice appreciated a always.

```
$(function() {

$("#test two").change(function() {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                }).multipleSelect({
                    width: '100%'
                });
            });
```

Comment: You're not supposed to have spaces in the ID.  Replace them with hyphens or underscores.

Comment: It's improper HTML to have spaces in id values.

Comment: `id="test two"`  yep! I didn't ever seen

Comment: Thanks, I know it is not correct but still looking for a solution if you have any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery IDs with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces)

Comment: Even if you can make a valid selector, you can't guarantee the behaviour in all browsers.  Fix the problem - remove the space.

Comment: if the OP doesn't care about old browser he can continue to use spaces in the IDs, HTML5 accepts this kind of characters into the attributes.

Comment: @rikpg No, it doesn't. It allows pretty much everything **but** spaces: "The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. **The value must not contain any space characters.**" [Source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ooops! my bad, you are so right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery documentation has a comprehensive page on [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You'll find all of the selectors that you can use to query based on attributes (which the `id` is), but it also has this piece of advice:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

So you have two options:

```
$('#test\\ two')
```

or

```
$('[id="test two"]')
```

All of that said, the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) doesn't allow spaces in the `id` attribute on elements. The browser will probably still render the page as you'd expect, but you really shouldn't do it if you can avoid it; if only because it makes things much more complicated than they need to be, as you've found out.

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

Answer (score 5):

Like so

```js
$("select[id='test two']").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple"  id="test two">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
</select>
```

*It's possible (use space in ID) but better don't use id with space, add `_` to your selector, like `'#text_two'`*

Answer (score 3):

Space is not a valid character in the ID attribute in HTML4 and in HTML5 too.  By the way you can use an attribute selector:

```
$("[id='test two']").change( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but it causes a break in the jquery.
`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for=test two]`

Comment: maybe you have an errore somewhere else, as you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLmjra42/ this kind of selector works smoothly!

Comment: Yeah I think it might be that the jquery multi select doesnt like this, jquery itself is fine with it... I have referenced ID's with spaces successfully with your method in the passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an attribute selector like so:

```
$("[id='test two']").change(function{
    // Logic here...
});
```

Alternatively, you could change the id to a class...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use spaces when you select element by id attribute,because  space character is not a valid for ID attribute.why not follow convention?.

> ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by
>   any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

if you don't care any kind of convention then select like the way other answer suggests.

```
$("select[id='test two']").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

**@courtesy** Alexander