# Selecting element with a space separeted words

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am adding elements in my view dynamically, like this:

```
@foreach ($categoryViews as $key => $value)
    <div class="large-2 columns text-center">
        <div id='{{ $key }}' style="height: 101px; width: 102px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

But one of my keys is a string that is space separated, it looks like this `Product test`

I know ids must not be separated, but I am trying to find a way to select somehow those elements, beacause I will be getting them from my DB, so instead of going through changes of making slugs for them, I was wondering how would I achieve that with jQuery, and I thought it was possible to do it since there was already a topic about it on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces). In my script I am trying to initiate charts for each element, by going through an the same array. I am using `$('[id=' + key + ']')` as a selector for space separated words by following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces), like this:

```
for (var key in icoop.viewsByCategory) {
    $('[id=' + key + ']').highcharts({
        // my code...
    }
```

In my console I get an error:

> jquery.js:1468Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id=Product test]

Comment: This isn't valid ID attribute. You would have better to use instead `data-id`

Comment: `id` attributes cannot have spaces in them. You need to remove the space from the `key` before you set it as the `id`

Comment: Agree with above comments, However if you still want to go with use `$('[id="' + key + '"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifier can't contain space, However still you need to use it then, the [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) can be used.

```
$('[id="' + key + '"]').highcharts()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

You cannot use ID with space, but you can store your data with spaces as attribute and find It with jQuery.

**Possible solution:**

```
@foreach ($categoryViews as $key => $value)
    <div class="large-2 columns text-center">
        <div data-name='{{ $key }}' style="height: 101px; width: 102px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

JavaScript code:

```
for (var key in icoop.viewsByCategory) {

    $('div[data-name=' + key + ']')[0].highcharts({

        // your code code...
    }
}
```

**Resume:**

```
<div data-name='some text'></div>

$("div[data-name='some text']")[0];
```

Comment: I know ids must not be separated, but I am trying to find a way to select somehow thoes elements, beacause I will be getting them from my DB, so instead of going through changes of making slugs for them, I was wondering how would I achieve that with jQuery, and I thought it was possible to do it since there was already a topic about it on stack overflow

Comment: You cannot name your element with incorrect ID. It is impossible. You can use another alternative ways. I will update my answer with possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ids cannot contain spaces or other blank characters (\t, \r, \n...). They just cannot. Doing this :

```
<span id='my id'></span>
```

Will assign two different Ids to `span`.