# Can't find certain elements with jQuery even though they are there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code stored as a variable:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <field id='Contact Name' required>
                <exists>$value<br></exists>
                <notexists></notexists>
            </field>
            <field id='Job Role' required>
                <exists>$value<br></exists>
                <notexists></notexists>
            </field>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is access this code and change the value of $value for each field based on inputs within my form and then render the final html inside of an iFrame.

Here is the JavaScript code I am using to do this:

```
function renderTemplate() {
    var template = $(selectedTemplate.html).contents(); //HTML code I have given above.
    $("input").each(function(index, input) {
        var element = $(input); //<input type="text" ref="Contact Name">
        if (element.attr("ref")) {
            var reference = element.attr("ref");
            var field = template.find("field[id='" + reference + "']");
            if (typeof(field) != undefined) {
                var exists = field.find("exists");
                var notExists = field.find("notexists");
                if (typeof(exists) != undefined && typeof(notexists) != undefined) {
                    if (element.val()) {
                        exists.html(exists.html().replace("$value", element.val()));
                    } else {
                        exists.html(notExists.html());
                    }
                    $('#signaturePreview').contents().find('html').html(template.html());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now for whatever reason, it cannot find the fields with the selector I'm giving.

I did some testing with the chrome console, and it can't find any fields at all, even when I use:

```
template.find("field") // Gives 0 results.
```

Comment: there is no input in the html. also where is the console part?

Comment: Those aren't valid HTML tags, you shouldn't be using them in the first place.

Comment: @guradio Because that's the html I'm modifying, not the html in my actual page. The inputs are there, trust me.

Comment: @Roberrrt I need them, though. That's not the issue.

Comment: Ok, you have `//<input type="text" ref="Contact Name">` then `var reference = element.attr("ref"); var field = template.find("field[id='" + reference + "']");` the `ref` value has a space in it, an id can't have a space - change it to `var field = template.find("field[ref='" + reference + "']");`

Comment: Even though the elements aren't valid, jQuery should still find them. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xn8zabrd/ - as Darren says, ID's can't have spaces. Have you tried simply `console.log(template)` ?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney The fields don't have a ref attribute. The inputs do. That's how I'm mapping the inputs to my elements.

Comment: Ok, but they still can't have spaces in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#..").contents().find("..")` will always return empty array, don't use `.contents`, ie:

```
var template = $(selectedTemplate.html);
```

---

To address some other issues:

1 spaces in IDs are not valid HTML, but you *can* select them using `[id=` https://stackoverflow.com/a/701958/2181514 .

2 jquery `.find` will return an empty array `[]`, not `undefined` when it can't find anything that matches. You would normall check length, eg:

```
var items = $("body").find("li.item");
if (items.length > 0) {
    ...
```