# Is it legal to use a string as an html id in html5?

Tags: html

Is it "correct" to put a string as an id? for example id="Nick Drake". I read here that in html4 it is not. It works well for my purpose, just wondering if it's right to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Possbile duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @Leonajs This "duplicate" was asked 8 years ago, well before html5.

Comment: This is cool: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem what so ever to use a string as an ID.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

This does mean however, that you should not use spaces in your ID. 
"Nick Drake" should become "Nick_Drake"

Source: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp
https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

If you ever have doubt about the validity of your html, run it through this service:

https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks. However, it still works with a blank space. So I'll use alt instead. Thanks again.

Comment: using spaces will work for most purposes, but some javascript selectors will run into problems with it.

Comment: @RockyRacoon See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces as an example why you should not use spaces.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> This attribute's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.). Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the class attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID.

Also, I don't know what your purpose is, but keep in mind that (emphasis is mine):

> This attribute's value is an opaque string: this means that web author must not use it to convey any information. **Particular meaning, for example semantic meaning, must not be derived from the string.**