# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #B%20Group

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simply dont understand why jquery `.click()` cannot be executed, cause everytime the element is fired I got an error you have seen in the title.

I have an element which is linked to my document by name `B Group` and I'm calling to that element like `$('a[href="#B Group"]')`. As you can see it has a space inside. Is it a misunderstanding for me or there cant be spaces inside?

**my code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.groups-activity .glyphicon-list',
        function () {
            var target = $(this).parents('tr');
            var name = target.find('td').slice(3, 4).text().trim();
            if ($('a[href = "#' + name + '"]').length > 0) {
                $('a[href="#' + name + '"]').click();
                return 0;
            }
            activityGroups.push(name);
            $('.tabs').append('<li class="groups tab col s3"><a data-admin="false" class="data-tab" href="#' + name + '">' + name + '</a><span class="close-tab">&times;</span></li>');
            $('a[href="#' + name + '"]').click();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Admin/CheckArray',
                data: { activityGroups: activityGroups }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery IDs with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces)

Comment: well it is inside a `href` property, indicating it should be a link. I believe JS is just HTML encoding it by changing the space to its HTML urlencode character `%20`, maybe that is why its not working

Comment: @N.Ivanov so is there a way to disable urlencoding?

Comment: @LabLab I guess you can simply use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: @N.Ivanov didn't work. jQuery automatically encodes text, so I can't pre-encode my `B Group`, because its simply text

Comment: well then do not uses spaces in IDs

Comment: @N.Ivanov this is a unique name that I receive from database, so the space should be there

Comment: Are you sure the `name` variable contains specified value? Appositely, you missed the `#` in `$('a[href="' + name + '"]').click();` line.

Comment: @Alexander yeap, im sure, thats an accident. I'll edit my answer's code